# problem with noUiSliderInput output having only 2 decimals

Tags: r, shiny, decimal

I'm trying to link a log scaled `noUiSliderInput` with a linear scaled `numericInput` without creating an eternal update loop. 
Normally I would stop the update lines with this:

```
input$Histoslider != log10(input$Threshold_box)
```

This created some issues with decimals, which I can't seem to fix properly. 
The main problem seems to be that noUiSliderInput always rounds its output to 2 decimals, causing the rounding problem for the conversion to 10^ and log10 back and forth

**Detailed description:**

I have an app where the user can set threshold filters in 2 ways:

1: type the number in a `numericInput` in un-transformed numbers

or

2: by changing the bar on a vertical `noUiSliderInput`.

The `noUiSliderInput` however is expressed as log10 numbers, as it is lined up with a plot of the data on log10 scale. so if the plot runs from 10^-1 to 10^4.5, the slider has values running from -1 to 4.5

The `numericInput` and `noUiSliderInputare` linked, so change one should update the other. 
This created a lot of difficulty with decimals. The `numericInput` has to be restricted in the app to 2 decimals. So to do that I add some transformation, rounding and transformation back again to get matching numbers.

I can get it to work for a normal `sliderInput`, but somehow not for a `noUiSliderInput`, eventhough they should spit out the same format of data.

The reason I have to stick with a `noUiSliderInput` is because I need a slider on both the x and y axis of the plot.

**Try to type 1256 in the numericInput to see an example of the problem**

**The app:**

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("dreamRs/shinyWidgets")
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

# function to see how many decimal places we need
decimalplaces <- function(x) {
  if ((x %% 1) != 0) {
    deci <- nchar(strsplit(sub('0+$', '', as.character(x)), ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][[2]])
    if(deci >2) { deci <- 2}
    return(deci)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}

# starting values for the sliders
minval <- round(-1, digits = 6)
maxval <- round(4.5, digits = 6)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
  div(numericInput("Threshold_box", "Normal value: ", min = 0, max = 100, value = 1, step=0.01), style = "display:inline-block") ),
  column(2, 
         # div(sliderInput( inputId = "Histoslider", label = NULL, min = minval, max = maxval, value = 0, step = 0.000001), style = 'display:inline-block; position:relative')
noUiSliderInput(inputId = "Histoslider", label = NULL, min = minval, max = maxval,  tooltips = FALSE, value = 0, step = 0.000001, direction = "rtl", orientation = "vertical", width = "100px", height = "276px")
   )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #setting decimals to 6 as that seemed to work in the end for a normal sliderInput
  values <- reactiveValues( transformDecimal = 2)

observeEvent(input$Threshold_box, { 
    if(!is.na(input$Threshold_box)) { values$transformDecimal <- decimalplaces(input$Threshold_box)
    if(input$Histoslider != log10(input$Threshold_box)) { 
      newval <- log10(input$Threshold_box)
      # updateSliderInput(session, 'Histoslider', value = newval)
      updateNoUiSliderInput(session, 'Histoslider', value = newval)
     }}}, ignoreInit = T)


  observeEvent(input$Histoslider, { 
    ## next three lines are to get matching set between a 2 decimal numer and the log value
    sliderFull <- 10^input$Histoslider
    sliderRound <- round(sliderFull, digits = values$transformDecimal)
    sliderLog <- log10(sliderRound)

    updateSliderInput(session, 'Histoslider', value = sliderLog)
    if(sliderLog != log10(input$Threshold_box)) { 
      updateNumericInput(session, 'Threshold_box', value = round(10^sliderLog, digits = values$transformDecimal))
    }
  }, ignoreInit = T)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```